# php:how to use a var outside a function inside a class

Tags: php, class

i made a function inside my class like that

```
public function admin_ads_manage(){

$ads728=$_POST['ads728'];
$ads600=$_POST['ads600'];
$ads300=$_POST['ads300'];



$file728=stripslashes(file_get_contents($this->dir_name."/ads/ads728.txt"));
$file600=stripslashes(file_get_contents($this->dir_name."/ads/ads600.txt"));
$file300=stripslashes(file_get_contents($this->dir_name."/ads/ads300.txt"));

if($_POST['submit']){

    $f728=fopen($this->dir_name."/ads/ads728.txt",'w');
    $w728=fwrite($f728,$ads728);

    $f600=fopen($this->dir_name."/ads/ads600.txt",'w');
    $w600=fwrite($f600,$ads600);

    $f300=fopen($this->dir_name."/ads/ads300.txt",'w');
    $w300=fwrite($f300,$ads300);

    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\" " ;


    }
```

i want to use the variable (only)  inside this function outside it to print the output in the index page,how to access to this function to allow to use only some var,not executing the whole function

i know i can execute the whole function by $object->function();
but i want only to use some var..........

Answer (score 0):

```
private $myVar;

public function admin_ads_manage(){
   $this->myVar = 'Your value';
   // Rest of the code
}

public function getMyVar() {
  return $this->myVar;
}

// Where you what to use it
echo $object->getMyVar();
```

Comment: thanks dotoree,i know this method,but i just asked if there is a method to access var outside function to use it only without making  another function to use it,suppose i made 100 var inside a function,making 100 functions to use every var only is a bad consuming time,i hope if my idea reached

Comment: If you want to CHANGE var in and out make it public as @Gediminas answered.

Answer (score 0):

Create public instance variable and access it.

```
class A
{
  public $var;
  public function admin_ads_manage()
  {
      //skip some code
      $this->var = "value to be accessed from outside";
  }
}
```